# Keras multi_gpu_model error: "swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'int64_t *', no destructor found"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, multi-gpu

I am using tensorflow 1.5.0, tensorflow-gpu 1.3.0, keras 2.0.9, keras-gpu 2.1.4

I created my model using this code:

```
inputs = Input([1,44,44,44])
x = Conv3D(64, (3,3,3), activation='relu', data_format='channels_first')(inputs)
x = Conv3D(16, (3,3,3), activation='relu', data_format='channels_first')(x)
x = Conv3D(1, (3,3,3), activation='relu', data_format='channels_first')(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

I wanted to use two GPUs on my machine.
But when I use

```
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)
```

I get this error:

```
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'int64_t *', no destructor found.
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'int64_t *', no destructor found.
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'int64_t *', no destructor found.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13359) in **tensorflow 1.3**. The [fix](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/4b9e50686928b858a0045e1ddcc0bab4acc7ff37) has been ported to 1.4 (and later, of course). You have `tensorflow` 1.5.0, but not `tensorflow-gpu` - 1.3.0. When you run `multi_gpu_model` from keras, it's clearly using `tensorflow-gpu` ops.

So you should update `tensorflow-gpu` to at least 1.4, the latest version would be even better.